# Heartbeat not taking its resource

Tags: linux, high-availability, heartbeat

So I have heartbeat installed, I followed a config guide where I literally changed the IP's of the guide and it's not working as it should :(.

The reason the eth numbers are obviously different.  I don't think that should have any effect on the resource handling though.  I used **uname -n** for the node names.  I have placed their ip's in the /etc/hosts file so they know about each other.

There is nothing suspicious in the logs.  Also Apache is set to listen on any interface available.

I cannot ping or reach the shared resource at all.  Any Ideas?

Here are my configs on my two servers that are running heartbeat.  They are aptly named loadb1 (192.168.1.101) and loadb2 (192.168.1.102) and their shared resource: 192.168.1.100.

## Loadb1's configs are:

**ha.cf**

```
logfile /var/log/ha-log
bcast eth0
keepalive 2
warntime 10
deadtime 30
initdead 120
udpport 694
udp eth0
auto_failback yes
node loadb1
node loadb2
#uuidfrom nodename
#respawn hacluster /usr/lib/heartbeat/ipfail
```

**haresources**

```
loadb1 IPaddr::192.168.1.100 httpd
```

**authkeys** (which is set to 600)

```
auth 2
2 crc
```

## Loadb2's configs are:

**ha.cf**

```
logfile /var/log/ha-log
bcast eth1
keepalive 2
warntime 10
deadtime 30
initdead 120
udpport 694
udp eth1
auto_failback yes
node loadb1
node loadb2
#uuidfrom nodename
#respawn hacluster /usr/lib/heartbeat/ipfail
```

**haresources**

```
loadb1 IPaddr::192.168.1.100 httpd
```

**authkeys** (which is set to 600)

```
auth 2
2 crc
```

When I run "service heartbeat status", I get:

```
heartbeat OK [pid xxxx et al] is running on loadb[x] [loadb[x]]...
```

depending on which server I'm on it will read loadb1 or loadb2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In haresources, try specifying the interface you want to have the shared address:

```
loadb1  192.168.1.100/24/eth0 httpd
```

or `/eth1` as appropriate (the `/24/` specifies the netmask, change that if appropriate).  If you do that, restart both HA processes, and it's still not working, can we get the output of `ifconfig -a` on both servers?

Edit: ah, that's probably not such a good idea.  [This page](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Haresources) says that

> Note that it is absolutely mandatory
>   for the haresources files to be
>   identical on both machines.

so you mustn't say `/eth0` on one machine, and `/eth1` on the other.  May we ask **why** one machine uses eth0 and the other eth1, and if there's any way of changing it?  And can we get the output of `ifconfig -a`, please?

Comment: great news!  adding the subnet mask (/32) made loadb1 take the resource.  However, when I simulate a failover, loadb2 doesn't take the resource.  Thank you for jostling my brain to attempt that!  Now, just getting loadb2 to work....

Comment: O.K.  I got it working.  Apparently heartbeat on loadb2 didn't like "service heartbeat restart"  I had to run: "service heartbeat stop" then "service heartbeat start" to get it to properly reload the config.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure how much help I was, but I'm very glad you've got it working.  Good luck with it!

Comment: It was the subnet mask that made it work.  You helped me think to try adding the subnet mask /32 to haresources.  :)